# While creating the REST API documentation using Swagger 2.0 getting this error

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Why am I getting the "operation cannot have multiple body parameters" error in the Swagger Editor?

[image: operation cannot have multiple body parameters]

Comment: you have multiple body-parameters in one of your api-methods, what is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is exactly what it states, "operation cannot have multiple body parameters". In your example the error is in the `POST /company/fastbill/customers` operation.

A `body` parameter represents the request body. So if you want to POST multiple data objects, you need to combine them into a single object payload. For example:

```
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              customer_details:
                $ref: '#/definitions/Customer'
              bank_account:
                type: object
                properties:
                  sources:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: '#/definitions/BankAccount'
```